# Powershell v2 | Script Won't Declare Variable, need help debugging

Tags: powershell

Alright there seems to be several issues with the script and i can't seem to figure out any of them, also some feedback on the script would be greatly apperciated. This is still my first script so it probably needs lots of little tweaks so please tell me whatever suggestions comes to mind.

Issues: Mostly all issues revolve around the logging.

1. Log file is not being checked so the script keeps adding computers to the log file over and over.
2. The log file does not update the information that is generated such as os,mac,ip, etc.

Issues Being Displayed:

> Property 'Result' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it
>   exists. At W:\Powershell Scripting\Test Lab\TestFunction.ps1:86
>   char:17
>   +         IF ($Computer. <<<< Result -ne "Successful") {
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (.:OperatorToken) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

The Script

```
Set-PSDebug -strict
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$consoleObject = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI

# Adjustable Variables
$Computers_Path = ".\computers.txt"
$Log_Path = ".\Log.txt"
$Log_MaxTick = 5
$RunOnServers = 0

# Multi-Threading Variables
$Jobs_MaxAtOnce = 20
$SleepTimer = 500

# Script Specific Variables
$ScriptTitle = "Local Admin Check"

# Validate Adjustable Variables
$Computers = @(Import-CSV $Computers_Path -header "Name","MAC")

# Framework Specific Variables (Pre-Setting Variables)
$Run = 0; $Succssful = 0; $Jobs_Count = 0; $Log_Tick= 0; $WriteToLog = "No"

# Misc
$Total = $Computers.length
IF (!(Test-Path $Log_Path)) { Add-Content $Log_Path "Name,OS,Mac,IPAddress,Status,Attempts,Result,LastAttempt" }
$Log = @(Import-Csv $Log_Path)
$Successful = ($Log | Where-Object {$_.Result -eq "Successful"} | Select-String -inputobject {$_.Name} -pattern $Computers | Measure-Object).Count

# Load Functions
Function GetOS {
    $RegCon = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Computer.Name )
    $RegKey = $RegCon.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\")
    $RegValue = $RegKey.GetValue("ProductName")
    $RegCon.Close()
    $Computer.OS = $RegValue
}

Function SmartLogging {

    If ($Args[0] -eq "AddComputer") {
        Add-Content ($Computer.Name + "," + $Computer.OS + "," + $Computer.Mac + "," + $Computer.IPAddress + "," + $Computer.Status + "," + $Computer.Attempts + "," + $Computer.Result + "," + $Computer.LastAttempt) -path .\log.txt
    } ELSEIF ( $Log_Tick -eq $Log_MaxTick -OR $Args -eq "Update" ) {
        $Log_Tick = 0;
        Get-Content $Log_Path | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$Computer.Name,.*", ($Computer.Name + "," + $Computer.OS + "," + $Computer.Mac + "," + $Computer.IPAddress + "," + $Computer.Status + "," + $Computer.Attempts + "," + $Computer.Result + "," + $Computer.LastAttempt)} | Set-Content $Log_Path
    } ELSEIF ($Args[0] -eq "CheckComputer") {
         IF (!($Log | Select-String -pattern $Computer.Name -SimpleMatch)) {
            $Log += New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name = $Computer.Name; OS = $NULL; Mac = $Computer.MAC; IPAddress = $NULL; Status = $NULL; Attempts = 0; Result = $NULL; LastAttempt = $NULL;}
            $Computer = $Log | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $Computer.Name}
            SmartLogging AddComputer
        } ELSE {
            $Computer = $Log | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $Computer.Name}
        }
    } ELSEIF (-not $Args[0]) {
        "Log Ticked"
        $Log_Tick++
    }
}

Function GetIPAddress {
    $IPAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("TrinityTechCorp") | Where-Object {$_.IPAddressToString -like "*.*.*.*"};
    $Computer.IPAddress = $IPAddress.IPAddressToString
}

Function WindowTitle {
    [int]$Successful_Percent = $Successful / $Total * 100
    $consoleObject.WindowTitle = “$ScriptTitle - $Successful Out Of $Total ($Successful_Percent%) Successful `| Run`: $Run”
}

# Start Script
while ( $Successful -le $Total ) {
    $Run++
    ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
        WindowTitle 
        SmartLogging CheckComputer
        IF ($Computer.Result -ne "Successful") {
            IF (test-connection $Computer.Name -quiet ) {
                $Computer.Status = "Awake"
                IF (!$Computer.OS){GetOS}
                IF (!$Computer.IPAddress){GetIPAddress}
                ## Start Script ##
                    $CheckComputer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $Computer.Name + ",computer")
                    $Group = $CheckComputer.psbase.children.find("Administrators")
                    $members= $Group.psbase.invoke("Members") | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
                    ForEach($user in $members) {
                        $Result = $Computer.Name + "," + $user.ToString()
                        Add-Content $Result -path .\Result.csv
                    }
                ## End Script ##
                SmartLogging Update
                $Computer.Result = "Successful"
                $Successful += 1
            } ELSE {
                $Computer.Status = "Unknown"
            }
            $Computer.Attempts = [int] $Computer.Attempts + 1
            $Computer.LastAttempt = Get-Date -uFormat "%I:%M:%S%p %d%b%y"
        }
    SmartLogging
    }
}
Write-Output "Script Completed"
```

Comment: Too much code in there. You might wanna look into reducing your sample to something smaller than can easily reproduce the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration of $Computers collection....

```
$Computers = @(Import-CSV $Computers_Path -header "Name","MAC")
```

...will not work with this condition:

```
IF ($Computer.Result -ne "Successful")
```

The exception message explicitly states this, and where:

> Property 'Result' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists. \TestFunction.ps1:86 char:17

To resolve this, I would recommend initializing the property of Result, most likely like so:

```
$Computers = @(Import-CSV $Computers_Path -header "Name","MAC","Result")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem this time is that you don't have `Result` member in `$Computers` collection member, only `Name` and `MAC`. Unless you add such a member later on your code, which I don't really want to read, as it already is about 100 rows and contains *a lot* of code that is *not* related to the actual problem statement.

```
$Computers = @(Import-CSV $Computers_Path -header "Name","MAC")
```

Have you tried debugging the script on Powershell ISE? It's built-in debugger for Powershell 2. Take a look at a [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx) about it.

Comment: As an alternative to PS ISE, you can use powerGUI script editor for debugging. It works well for v2.